# Jenkins Pipeline sh step hangs

Tags: linux, bash, jenkins

I am currently having an issue with Jenkins running on Ubuntu 18.04. The sh pipeline step hangs and eventually times out with the following message:

```
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/members-only-demo@tmp/durable-494a3b0d
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
Cannot contact : java.io.FileNotFoundException: File '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/members-only-demo@tmp/durable-494a3b0d/output.txt' does not exist
```

Here is the thread dump:

```
Thread #6
    at DSL.sh(completed process (code -2) in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/members-only-demo@tmp/durable-494a3b0d; recurrence period: 15000ms; check task scheduled; cancelled? false done? false)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:9)
    at DSL.stage(Native Method)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:8)
    at DSL.node(running on )
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
```

The pipeline script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
node {
        stage('Checkout') {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/da-demo']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'TeamHub2', url: 'hth@helixteamhub.cloud:digitalarchitects/projects/slender-man/repositories/git/members-only-app']]])
        }
        stage('Create Build Dir') {
            sh label: '', returnStdout: true, script: 'rm --recursive --force ${env.WORKSPACE}/build/'
            sh 'mkdir --parents ${env.WORKSPACE}/build/coverage ${env.WORKSPACE}/build/logs ${env.WORKSPACE}/build/pdepend'
        }
   ...
}
```

I am not really sure how to troubleshoot this issue. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling jenkins using apt-get --purge remove jenkins then apt-get install jenkins. Sadly everything must be configured again, but the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

After plugins update had the same issue with Jenkins k8s nodes, turns out that default workingDir value for default jnlp k8s node is now set to `/home/jenkins/agent`, whereas for second container in pod I set it to `/home/jenkins`.

Switching workingDir to `/home/jenkins/agent` for the second container in pod fixed the problem.

Comment: I had a similar issue but on a Windows node (yes using sh hung), the issue was that my workingDir was set to /temp (which is invalid on windows), after changing it to "C:\temp" it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
It was due to kubernetes pod security Policy.
after relaxing pod policy it was ok.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.